# How to construct an LP to achieve roundup in objective function?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Objective: Minimize 500 * Roundup(x/1200) + 1000 * Roundup(y/3200)

Variables: x,y

Constraints: x + y = 8000

Is there a way to construct an LP without breaking the linearity conditions for the problem above?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'LP', but this problem seems receptive to the Lagrange Multiplier Method.

Comment: @rt6 LP means Linear Programming or Linear Program.

Answer (score 1):

Using integer variables you can do:

$$\begin{align}
    \min\> & 500 b_1 + 1000 b_2\\
         & b_1 \ge x/1200 \\
         & b_2 \ge y/3200 \\
         & \text{other constraints}\\
         &b_1, b_2 \text{ integer} \\
         &x, y \ge 0
\end{align}$$

This is no longer an LP but now a (linear) MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without taking away from [the formulation given by Erwin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432701/how-to-construct-an-lp-to-achieve-roundup-in-objective-function/2432825#2432825), I'd actually formulate it as follows:

$$\begin{align}
    \min\> & 500 b_1 + 1000 b_2\\
         & 1200 \,b_1 \ge x\\
         & 3200 \,b_2 \ge y\\
         & x + y = 8000\\
         &b_1, b_2 \text{ integer} \\
         &x, y \ge 0.
\end{align}$$

This formulation can be simplified as follows:

$$\begin{align}
    \min\> & 500 b_1 + 1000 b_2\\
         & 1200 \,b_1 \ge x\\
         & 3200 \,b_2 \ge 8000 - x\\
         &b_1, b_2 \text{ integer} \\
         &0 \le x \le 8000,
\end{align}$$

where we remove $y$ from the model by substituting $y=8000-x$. You can now try to find the *convex hull* of the above MILP to obtain the corresponding Linear Program (LP).

Comment: In general, for large, sparse LPs, I do not recommend to substitute out variables and equalities. In most cases, a large and sparse model solves faster than a smaller but denser one.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Of course, if an equivalent LP of an IP requires an exponential number of constraints/variables, then it is probably not possible to solve larger instances with the LP. However, solving an LP is often a lot more easier than the IP because its worst case can be solved in polynomial time. Here, the number of non-zero elements in the simplified formulation is smaller than that of the original one. So I think even without finding and solving the LP it will be solved faster than the original model (note that the number of variables and constraints are also reduced).

Comment: In general, I don't agree with this statement. Substituting out continuous variables from a MIP is often (but not always) a bad idea. We agree to disagree on this point.

Comment: By the way, from my own experience it is sometimes better to formulate a set of constraints with an inequality rather than equality (when possible). Of course, this is not a general rule (e.g., in case of special ordered sets) but usually works for solvers.

Comment: This does not make sense to me,